# How to retrieve current logged in user data?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

hello I'm trying to retrieve the user's first name to show it in the main page after login (I'll assign it to UILabel).

My database:
[image]

This is the code I'm trying :

```
let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
func getName(Completion: @escaping((String) -> ())) {
   let DocRefernce:DocumentReference!
   DocRefernce = db.collection("users").document(id)
   DocRefernce.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
       if error != nil {
           print(error!)
       } else {
           guard let snapshot = docSnapshot, snapshot.exists else { return }
           guard let data = snapshot.data() else { return }
           let firstname = data["FirstName"] as? String ?? "No name"
           Completion(firstname)
           
       }
   }
}
```

and I'm calling the method in `override func viewDidLoad()`

```
getName{ [self] (name) in
   fullName.text = name
}
```

I'm using swift with cloud firestore and I'm new to it I appreciate any help

Comment: Hint: for doc in snapshot.documents {}

Comment: hello thank you so much for your help but unfortunately the solution you gave me didn't work at first but i did change some things in my firebase and it  worked with some additions thank you again I'm new to stack overflow I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to determine what document to load is:

```
db.collection("users").document(id)
```

But when we look at your database, the `uid` field in the selected document has a different value than the document ID. So it looks like you didn't store the document under the user's UID, which explains why this code won't load the user's document.

---

To find the document for the current UID, you will need to [user a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) on the `uid` field.

```
let query = db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: id)
```

When you [execute this query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) you get a query snapshot with possible multiple documents, since there may be multiple documents with a matching `uid` field.

---

While the above works with your current data structure, I recommend changing your data structure. If each user can only have a single document in the `users` collection, it is idiomatic to use the UID as the document ID, instead of letting Firestore generate a document ID.

So instead of calling `addDocument()` to add the user document, use `document(uid).setData(...)` as also shown in the documentation on [writing a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Comment: i did that t0 the code and it's working now  `guard let thisUId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let query : Query = db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: thisUId)
        query.getDocuments ( completion:  {(snapShot, errror) in
            guard let ds = snapShot, !ds.isEmpty else {
                //error 
                return}
            if let userData = ds.documents.last {
                let firstname = userData["FirstName"] as? String ?? ""
                completion(firstname) } })`

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @user17180809! 